# Swagger: support for optional routes

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, swagger-2.0

I have a route with an optional parameter:

```
    [Route("{categoryId?}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int? categoryId=null)
```

However, when I don't provide a value for `categoryId` the call includes `{categoryId?}` in the request itself...

```
http://myhost/api/%7BcategoryId%7D
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swagger has no support for optional path parameters. If you wish to document it this way, you'd have to create two separate paths - one without the path parameter and one with.

Comment: Yes, the answer is still relevant today.