# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Swagger(swashbuckle) Url template optional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-2.1, swashbuckle

```
[HttpGet("commercial/{fromCcy}/{toCcy?}")]
public ActionResult Commercial(string fromCcy, string toCcy)
```

I have action "commercial" with optional parameter "toCcy" and swagger spec generates with required field. Is there any way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional WebAPI routing parameters with Swagger documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512923/optional-webapi-routing-parameters-with-swagger-documentation), [Make parameters in swashbuckle optional(not required)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46510901/113116) and [Swagger: support for optional routes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30182657/113116)

Comment: @Helen Thanks for your comment, as you linked me this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512923/optional-webapi-routing-parameters-with-swagger-documentation I created two separate methods(overloaded) and it works, generates two separate paths but it is not right decision, I'd be happy if Swagger Team adds {toCcy?} like optional parameters to it's specs.

Comment: OpenAPI Spec enhancement request to support optional path parameters: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/622

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use optional parameters, the best way is use [Fromquery]. For example:

```
[HttpGet("commercial")]
public ActionResult Commercial([FromQuery] OptionsViewModel viewModel)
{
...
}

public class OptionsViewModel
{
    public string FromCcy { get; set; }
    public string ToCcy { get; set; }
}
```

Then Swagger shows all parameters as optional:

```
Swagger UI Parameters:

Name    Description
FromCcy
string
(query)  

ToCcy
string
(query)
```

Comment: This helped me and I also added attribute [Required] to FromCcy property of OptionsViewModel class and it works. Thanks!